# struggle for javascript porting to dart

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Original javascript code I like to port to Dart.

```js
hterm.defaultStorage = new lib.Storage.Chrome(chrome.storage.sync);
```

I have tried

```dart
js.context['hterm']['defaultStorage'] = 
    new js.JsObject(js.context['lib']['Storage']['Chrome'], js.context['chrome']['storage']['sync']);
```

but this doest work as I expected. perhaps, because js.JsObject returns dart object.
Do I have to use `JsObject.jsify` ?  it seems that `jsify` receive collection of dart object only.

Comment: Hm. I'm just going to extract pure javascript code to separate file. and call it from dart.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should work this way

```dart
js.context['hterm']['defaultStorage'] = 
    js.context['lib']['Storage'].callMethod('Chrome', [js.context['chrome']['storage']['sync']]);
```